# Using integer from one class in another Android

Tags: android

I need some help with using integer from one activity to another.

I am making some basic math program(game). It gets two random numbers, random operator, and 30 secs to solve math problems as much as you can.

If you solve problem u get 1 point.

Anyway right now, I want to get number of points that user have made and use it in another activity called `*RankActivity*.`

Main activity is called `*BrzoRacunanjeActivity*` and it contains button and one `*int*` called `*poenibrojanje*` which get number of points that user have made, and when I click on button, it opens new Activity with this line:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, RankActivity.class));
```

As you can see another Activity is called RankActivity, and there  I wrote :

```
*BrzoRacunanjeActivity a1 = new BrzoRacunanjeActivity();*

*System.out.println("Number of points:" + a1.poenibrojanje);;*
```

and I get all time this `reuslt: 09-22 09:09:14.940: INFO/System.out(289):` Number of points:0

Comment: so you want to pass integer value from one activity to another activity?

Comment: I updated my answer check it will work.

Comment: remove BrzoRacunanjeActivity a1 = new BrzoRacunanjeActivity();*

Comment: Hey dude, if you have time, can you take look at this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7515967/alertdialog-with-counddowntimer-android-help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all make
 static variable like as `public static int poenibrojanje;`
 in your `BrzoRacunanjeActivity.class` file now you can use this variable in any other class like as

```
 BrzoRacunanjeActivity.poenibrojanje
```

or you can use `putExtras();` method.

in you main activity.

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, RankActivity.class);
i.putExtra("Value",poenibrojanje);
```

in your next activity

```
int v = (getIntent().getExtras().getInt("Value")) ;
```

Comment: Well, that was first thing that i have tried. It seems that it works on regular Java, not on Android.

Comment: it is working also in android.. and you can also use putExtras

Comment: It seems that it works with just putting:                         public static int poenibrojanje;                                         Intent intent = new Intent(BrzoRacunanjeActivity.this, RankActivity.class); startActivity(intent);                                  RankActivity:                                                                 BrzoRacunanjeActivity a1 = new BrzoRacunanjeActivity();                                    System.out.println(a1.poenibrojanje);

Comment: i think dont need to write **BrzoRacunanjeActivity a1 = new BrzoRacunanjeActivity();**  but you can direct use like this **BrzoRacunanjeActivity.poenibrojanje**

Comment: Yeah, I know, but I think this way is a little bit faster. Anyway, thanks for help. Cheers :)

Comment: If you have time, can you take look at this problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7515967/alertdialog-with-counddowntimer-android-help

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, RankActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("points", pointsVar);
startActivity(intent);
```

In `onCreate` of `RankActivity`:

```
getIntent().getIntExtra("points", 0);
```

Comment: I'm sorry for that, it's `getIntent()`. Hmpf and not `getExtraInt`. I corrected that...

Comment: When I put brackets on getIntent,I get this error: The method getExtraInt(String) is undefined for the type Intent

Comment: Sorry again, see comment obove your's

Answer (score 4):

so you want to pass integer value from one activity to another activity? right...

**try:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(currentclass.this, destination.class);

intent.putExtra("point", pointvalue);

startActivity(intent);
```

at **destination activity:**

```
final int getpoint = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("point");
```

This will solve your problem.

Comment: I have tried, but without brackets on getIntent, it cant be resolved, and when I write getIntent().getExtraInt("point"); I get this error: The method getExtraInt(String) is undefined for the type Intent.

Comment: Have you extended class with Activity?