# can I use activiy one time(register activity) and switch the main launcher to different activity?

Tags: android

can I use activiy one time(register activity) and switch the main launcher after using to different activity?

another question if I may,
If I create parameter x in one of the activities in my application, can I use this parameter in other activities?...If yes, how I can do that?

thanks :)

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't call the registration activity from the main activity if a certain configuration has not yet been created or something like that? Using the same parameters for several activities can be achieved by adding them to the calling Intent's extras or by using SharedPreferences.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot dynamically change the launcher activity once it has to be only 1 activity that is defined in the manifest file.

I would recommend having something like a landing or splash activity which checks a shared preference variable, to decide which activity to launch, for example either a login activity or another activity.

You should not access a variable in an activty from another activity, you should store these in data holding classes. however if you want to do it, for a good reason, simply make it static.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot adjust the manifest after running your application. What you can do is have your default launcher activity write to [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) once it has been run once. Inside of that activity check to see if that preference has been set and if it has just finish that activity and launch your new activity, the user will not see anything if you do this in the onCreate of the launcher activity.

As for passing params between activities you should use intent extras. For example to pass a string use [putExtra(String key, String value)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), and to get that parameter inside of the new activity use [getStringExtra("Key")](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getStringExtra%28java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 0):

For global variables accessable from different activities you can also extend Application class and then access it via getApplicationContext().

Answer (score 0):

**1. One time activity launch**

You can't change the main launcher. It's a static information. What you could do is following:

```
// in the beginning of onCreate
// first launch could be loaded from shared preferences
// see 2. for more
if (!firstLaunch) {
    // start another activity
    finish();
    return;
}
```

**2. Use data in another activity**

One way is to persist the data and load it somewhere else. You will find all information you need in the [Data Storage article](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).

If your data is primitive you could try to pass it by intent to another activity. See [Using integer from one class in another Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7512543/using-integer-from-one-class-in-another-android/7512601).

If it is complex you could try to implement an own [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) class and use helper methods to access global data. See [Android: Accessing resources without an Activity or Context reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531959/android-accessing-resources-without-an-activity-or-context-refeerence/7532134#7532134).
Be careful with that, please read the [Avoiding Memory Leaks article](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/avoiding-memory-leaks.html) then.